# Type of Generic List is equal to to List of objects

Tags: flutter

hello guys I am using a generic class which handle the response which comes from the API. Actually I am using a dynamic method which will return back a result based on the Generic class type. it is working fine for single object but i am struggling with the check of type for list of objects

```
  class Result<T> {
     T Data;
     bool IsSuccess = false;
     int HttpCode;
     List<String> ErrorList = <String>[];

    Result({this.Data, this.IsSuccess, this.HttpCode,this.ErrorList});

   Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   IsSuccess = json['isSuccess'];
   HttpCode = json['httpCode'];
   if(json['data'] != null){
   Data = resultFromJson<T>(json['data']);
   }
  if (json['errorList'] != null) {
  ErrorList = <String>[];
  json['errorList'].forEach((v) {
    ErrorList.add(v as String);
    });
    }
 }
 dynamic resultFromJson<T>(Object object) {
Type type = T;
 // here it is working fine
if (type == UserModel) {
  return UserModel.fromJson(object);
}
 // but it doesn't work for list of objects
if (type is List<VehicleModel>) {
  var ls = object as List<dynamic>;
  return ls.map((e) => VehicleModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i used to convert type to string and it works fine

type.toString() == "List"

Answer (score -1):

Does your data format with json with a iterable of list of object? Try use quicktype.io in order generate a class model for you.

Comment: i used to convert type toString then i compare it as follow type.toString() == "List<VehicleModel>" then it works